# Rendered PHP Variable outside of the img src element, need escaping advice

Tags: php

Hey guys, I have the following code:

```
foreach($collection as $img)
   {
$image_id = $img['imageid'];
$thumbwidget  = wp_get_attachment_image_src($image_id, 'full');
$gallery  .= '<a class="fav-image-a" href="http://www.bangstyle.com/haircut-detail/?uid='.$uid.'&img_id='.$image_id.'&ucolid='.$user_id.'&catid='.$col_id.'&theater">';
$gallery .= '<img src="';
$gallery .= thumbGen($thumbwidget[0],259,320,'valing=top');
$gallery .= '">';
$gallery  .= '</a>';                
   }
```

I think I may have the wrong order of escaping. The rendered variable is not staying within the `img src` when rendered. I assume it has to do with my escaping somewhere.

The `live url` can be seen at http://bangstyle.com/test-widget/

You can see what's happening. The rendered elements are on top.

Comment: $gallery .= '<img src="'.$thumbwidgeturl.'">';

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why the extra quotes inside?  What you are producing is this:

```
<img src="'THUMBWIDGETURL_IS_INSERTED_HERE'">
```

What you probably want is this:

```
<img src="THUMBWIDGETURL_IS_INSERTED_HERE">
```

To do that just remove the extra \':

```
$gallery .= '<img src="'.$thumbwidgeturl.'">';
```

---

Rules to be aware of:

- In PHP, both single quotes and double quotes can be used to produce string literals.
- Each should be used in a pair and that pair constitutes one string literal.  So, in your example you have two string literals and a variable being combined (concatenated) with the dot (`.`) operator.
- Inside single quotes, single quotes need to be escaped, and inside double quotes, double quotes need to be escape.  The other type of quotes in each can be used freely without escaping.
- Strings inside single quotes are taken as they are, while strings inside double quotes are *interpreted* for variables.
- More information in the [PHP docs on Strings](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.double).

Comment: its relative location of the image

Comment: @NikolaosVassos Please see edits.  If you are trying to produce raw HTML, I think you have extra quotes inside.

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
$gallery .= "<img src=\"" . $thumbwidgeturl . "\">";
```

or even:

```
$gallery .= '<img src="' . $thumbwidgeturl . '">';
```